# lpIsolveApi, solution outside of constraints

Tags: r, lpsolve

I am at a wits end, please help!  below is the setup for the problem.  by the way, why         is it that I can't view the model detail when there are more than 8 variables?

I have set up the constraints to bound the answer to within window. The solution provided     for variable 10 is outside of constraint.  is there something I am missing?

```
[25,] "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "1" "0" "0" "0" "<="   "0.0096"      
[26,] "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "1" "0" "0" "0" ">"    "-0.0096"           
[27,] "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "1" "0" "0" "0" "<="   "0.00096"          
[28,] "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "1" "0" "0" "0" ">"    "-0.00096"        
[29,] "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "1" "0" "0" "<="   "0.029"         
[30,] "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "1" "0" "0" ">"    "-0.029"       
[31,] "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "1" "0" "0" "<="   "0.0029"       
[32,] "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "1" "0" "0" ">"    "-0.0029"       
[33,] "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "1" "0" "<="   "0.014"        
[34,] "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "1" "0" ">"    "-0.014"      
[35,] "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "1" "0" "<="   "0.0014"        
[36,] "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "1" "0" ">"    "-0.0014"       
[37,] "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "1" "<="   "0.0028"        
[38,] "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "1" ">"    "-0.0028"         
[39,] "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "1" "<="   "0.00028"            
[40,] "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "1" ">"    "-0.00028"       
[41,] "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "="    "0"            

Browse[2]> n        
debug at #60: cat(get.objective(lpIr), "\n")         
Browse[2]> get.variables(lpIr)           
 [1]  0.00284  0.00024  0.00038  0.00112  0.00210  0.00778  0.00096  0.00290  0.00140     -0.01972        

tRatio <- (tDelta+IR*factor)      
set.objfn(lpIr,tRatio)       
lp.control(lpIr,sense='max')
```

Roland,

I added the source code.  initial post did not include because i thought the browser output showed the setup.  appreciate your help in advance.

set.bounds(lpIr,lower=rep(-100,10))
    ##set objective direction, Maximize Information Ratio

```
constMat <- matrix(0.0,nrow=41,ncol=length(delta))
rightV <-rep(NA,41)
constV <-rep(NA,41)

for (i in 1:10)
{
    inx = ((i-1)*4) 

    constMat[inx+1,i] <- 1  

    rightV[inx+1] <- (pWeight[i]*.2)-actWeight[i]
    constV[inx+1] <- "<="

    constMat[inx+2,i] <- 1  
tmp1 = (pWeight[i]*-.2)-actWeight[i]  
    rightV[inx+2] <-  tmp1
    constV[inx+2] <- ">"

    constMat[inx+3,i] <- 1  
tmp1 = (pWeight[i]*.02)
rightV[inx+3] <- tmp1
constV[inx+3] <- "<="

constMat[inx+4,i] <- 1  
tmp1 = (pWeight[i]*-.02)
    rightV[inx+4] <- tmp1
    constV[inx+4] <- ">"
} 

constMat[41,]<-rep(1,10)
rightV[41] <- 0
constV[41] <- "="

for (i in 1:10)
{
    set.column(lpIr,i,constMat[,i])
}

tDelta<- delta
tRatio <- (tDelta+IR*factor)
set.objfn(lpIr,tRatio)
```

##   cat(rightV,"\n")

```
set.rhs(lpIr,rightV)
set.constr.type(lpIr,constV)  
solve(lpIr,-l)  
cat(get.objective(lpIr),"\n")
##cat(tRatio,"\n")
cat(get.variables(lpIr),"\n")   
res = get.variables(lpIr)
```

Comment: Why are you showing us `browser` output? How are we suposed to interpret it with the meager information you provide?

Comment: I included the source code.  I thought the browser output made the setup transparent.  also, I set the objective twice.  for some reason, initial objfn does not set the objective function.

Comment: Could you post a reproducible example? One that we can recreate and see where the problem is? You haven't supplied many values such as delta, pWeights etc. Once you do that, we can help you diagnose the problem.